# Cannot find module for aliased module in weback

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs

In webpack, I've set an alias for a library

```
resolve: {
 alias: {
  "@local/module": path.resolve(__dirname, "..path")
 }
}
```

When running jest on a component that uses this module, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module '@local/module' from 'Component.tsx'
```

I've tried including the following in my `jest.config.js` with no success

```
moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Jest doesn't know about Webpack's aliases. You'll need to use Jest's own alias system to define the same aliases.

In your `jest.config.js`, add a `moduleNameMapper` key like this:

```
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@local/module": "<rootDir>/src/module"
  }
}
```

It also supports Regex for dynamically rewriting paths. See [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `path.resolve(__dirname, "..", path)`